# API key for Upwork looks to be disabled

Tags: upwork-api

My API key (...e3d4) says its now disabled in the console at https://www.upwork.com/services/api/keys. I don't see how to get it working again.

Comment: Perhaps you should  contact their support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual reasons for your API key to be disabled are the following:

- Rate limits violation
- Terms of Use violations
- Using the API key for purposes different than the ones registered in
  the request form.

There are more details [here](https://developers.upwork.com/?lang=python#getting-started_rate-limits)
You will need to contact [support.upwork.com](https://support.upwork.com) to get it enabled again.